# ImageMagick on MAMP

Tags: php, imagemagick, mamp

I am trying to install ImageMagick on my Mac using MAMP using homebrew.

In the terminal I am not getting the following message:

```
Warning: php53-imagick-3.1.0RC2 already installed
```

When trying to run the install script, which was apparently successful, however I still receive the following error when trying to use ImageMagick from PHP:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in....
```

I'm amazed at how difficult this has been, if anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you including the extension in your php.ini?  Something like `extension=imagick.so`

Comment: Yes I have added: extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php53-imagick/3.1.0RC2/imagick.so"